# Sorting an object into composed array

Tags: javascript

I have an `object` made of names and numbers. Numbers belong to the names before them:

```
obj = [30, "name1", 8, "name2", 11, "name3", 14, "name4"]
```

I would like to sort it descending by the numbers and change it into composed array like this:

```
arr = [["name1", 30], ["name4", 14], ["name3", 11], ["name2", 8]];
```

I know it is pretty basic, but I have not used `JavaScript` for some time and I forgot a lot.

Comment: i dont see any way to associate those into pairs

Comment: Arrays are technically objects in js, but this looks like an array. Is it an array?

Comment: Well, I wanted it to be an array, but typeof() says it is an object :-)

Comment: you mean numbers belong to the names AFTER them

Comment: In obj the number 30 belongs to name1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
obj = [30, "name1", 8, "name2", 11, "name3", 14, "name4"]
arr = [];
var i,j;
for (i=0,j=obj.length; i<j; i+=2) {
    arr.push(obj.slice(i,i+2).reverse());
}
arr.sort(function(a, b){return a[1] < b[1];})
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```